# Existing Realm Database file not working with Realm 0.90.0

Tags: android, realm

I created Realm Database file using earlier versions of Realm. Due to errors in the previous production build, I am trying to update it to the new version but it failed

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug'.
> javassist.NotFoundException: io.realm.MyModelRealmProxyInterface
```

**Update**

After running `./gradlew clean assemble` -

```
:app:compileRetrolambdaDebug
:app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug'.
> javassist.NotFoundException: io.realm.MyModelRealmProxyInterface

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 9.423 secs
```

**Update 2**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24 rc1'

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.conem.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.3.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        /*debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }*/
    }
}

ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 55, 'armeabi-v7a': 56, 'arm64-v8a': 57, 'mips': 58, 'x86': 59, 'x86_64': 60]

import com.android.build.OutputFile

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // assign different version code for each output
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.versionCodeOverride =
                project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        /*output.versionNameOverride =
                String.valueOf(project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)) * 1000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
*/    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //compile files('libs/InMobi-5.2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/libadapterinmobi.jar')
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
    //compile files('libs/realm-android-0.87.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try to run `./gradlew clean assemble` from the command line?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior Updated the question after running `./gradlew clean assemble`

Comment: Able to compile but now this error `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8d689f44 in tid 2640 (AsyncTask #1)`

Comment: Sounds like there is something seriously wrong in your build somewhere. Can you post your entire build.gradle as well?

Comment: Check the updated question with build.gradle

Comment: How did you solve the compile exception> what is the full backtrace of `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8d689f44 in tid 2640 (AsyncTask #1)`

Comment: @beeenderThis is the runtime exception, not compile exception. Application just for closed there is no other stack trace.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, have you resolve it ?

Comment: @Baqir I remade the file using realm 1.0.0